# Completing object construction after GSON deserialization

Tags: java, android, json, gson

I have successfully started using GSON to serialize and de-serialize a hierarchy of objects in my Android application.

Some of the objects being serialized have members which I must mark as `transient` (or otherwise use alternative GSON annotations to prevent them being serialized) because they are references to objects that I do not want to serialize as part of the output JSON string. Those references are to objects which must be separately constructed by some other means.

Once the structure is de-serialized back into Java objects, at some point I need to fill in those references. I could easily do this perhaps by using a series of `setXXX()` type methods, but until that is done, those objects are in an incomplete state. What I am therefore wondering is whether there is a more robust approach to this.

Ways I have thought of so far:

1. Have the objects throw a `RuntimeException` (or something more suitable) if they're in an incomplete state; that is, if they're asked to do some work when some initialization method wasn't called.
2. Separate out the serializable bits into a separate data model object. In other words, take out the stuff that can't be serialized. After GSON de-serialization, build up my 'real' objects using those data objects in their composition. This seems to defeat the convenience of using GSON somewhat.
3. Write a custom deserializer for GSON to handle the special creation of those objects.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would likely take the second approach, because as I typically design my applications, anything that needs to be serialized/deserialized is really just plain old data, or POJOs if you prefer.  If I find myself needing to customize/configure the serialization API to do what I want, I tend to simplify what's being serialized, so the serialization API doesn't need the extra configurations.

So, if I have a more complicated data model, parts of which aren't to be serialized/deserialized, then I extract from it a simpler set of POJOs, as a conceptually separate data model to participate in the serialization/deserialization.  This does then indeed require an extra step to map between the two data models, but that's usually pretty simple, also.

If the third approach is preferred, then note also [the Instance Creator feature](https://sites.google.com/site/gson/gson-user-guide#TOC-Writing-an-Instance-Creator), as it can provide another useful hook into customizing the deserialization process.

Comment: Many thanks. I think I should take this second approach because another concern is that my JSON output I have presently is very tightly coupled to the actual class implementation, and I'm also concerned about versioning (it could get messy if JSON file loaded into a newer app vesion where the class structures have changed). Mapping the application classes to a tree of 'model' classes for the purpose of persistance seems to be a good way to solve all this. Silly question, but what terminology would you use to distinguish between a real working class and a data model class?

Comment: Maybe ViewModel, or PersistenceModel, or SerializedModel, or JsonModel, or IntegrationModel, or ServiceModel, or something else.

Answer (score 11):

Check out https://github.com/julman99/gson-fire

It's a library I made that extends Gson to handle cases like Post-serialization and Post-deserialization

Also it has many other cool features that I've needed over time with Gson.